# Jquery ajax call fails on android emulator

Tags: android, jquery, ajax

I am trying to invoke webservice using jquery ajax call. 
I am using jasonp as a datatype to fix cross domain issues.

It works fine in all browsers. i tested it on other domains. i am getting a valid responce.
When i try to run it from android device emulator webservice call fails.

Please suggest.

Code :

```
function getJsonData()
{
    alert("Within get json function.. ");
    (function($) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/mobile-services/rest/languages.json?callback=callback';
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
})(jQuery);
}
function callback(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
```

webservice response.

```
callback([{"language":"English","id":1},{"language":"Hindi","id":2},{"language":"Marathi","id":3}])
```

which is a valid jsonp response.

Android manifest file permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` --- so your webserver is embedded in your Android emulator?

Comment: No its not embedded on androide emulator. its on the same machine. I can access webservices through emulator browser.

Comment: Check the answer by Ajinkya below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web service URL try using  `10.0.2.2`  instead of `localhost`.
`localhost` or `127.0.0.1` points to emulator / android device while `10.0.2.2` is a special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e. `127.0.0.1` on your development machine). Check this [Link](http://juristr.com/blog/2009/10/accessing-host-machine-from-your/) for more details.